# Is Externally Sourced Configuration File Values Deprecated in Mongodb6?

Tags: mongodb, exec

I'm trying to configure mongod.conf to get certificateKeyPassword from a file instead of clear text.

```
net:
  tls:
  …
    certificateKeyFile: "/etc/tls/mongod.pem"
    certificateKeyFilePassword:
      __exec: "/home/ec2-usr/plaintextPassword"
      type: "string"
```

It doesn't run

systemctl status mongod shows invalid argument.

Is this deprecated?
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/expansion-directives/

Change the file to a bash script that echos the passphrase

Got this error after I ran

```
mongod -f mongod.conf --configExpand "exec"

{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-02T07:29:42.568Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23318,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Processing config expansion","attr":{"expansion":"__exec","node":"net.tls.certificateKeyFilePassword"}}
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 17827
ERROR: child process failed, exited with 1
```

Got this from mongod.log

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-02T07:29:42.577+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20574,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Error during global initialization","attr":{"error":{"code":140,"codeName":"InvalidSSLConfiguration","errmsg":"Can not set up PEM key file."}}}
```

Please help?

Comment: I got it.

It has more to do with whitespace than the hash.
https://www.percona.com/blog/externally-sourced-configuration-file-values-in-mongodb/